# remove variables from a data frame based on a column within another data frame in R

Tags: r

I want to remove a number of columns from df1

```
  | A      | B      | C      | D
  | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------
1 | 0.870  | 0.435  | 0.968  | 0.679
2 | 0.456  | 0.259  | 0.906  | 0.467
3 | 0.298  | 0.256  | 0.457  | 0.768
4 | 0.994  | 0.987  | 0.365  | 0.765
```

if they appear as values within a column called TEST within df2

```
  | TEST   |  
  | ------ | 
1 | A      | 
2 | B      |
```

Comment: This should work:

newDF = df1[, -which(colnames(df1) %in% df2$TEST)]

Comment: Thanks @jav, that works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1[,!(colnames(df1) %in% df2$TEST)]
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer from the comments which worked for me is:

```
newDF = df1[, -which(colnames(df1) %in% df2$TEST)]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `setdiff`

```
 df1[setdiff(names(df1), df2$TEST)]
```